# Tableau make one line out of two if same city name

Tags: tableau-api

Does anyone know if I can add two rows together so that I end up with just one row in Tableau (see screenshot)? So, if both rows are city Aachen and one row has a value for cost but not for purchasing power and the other row has a value for purchasing power but not cost, I would want just one row with both values. I am not interested in the columns "Table Name" and "Document Index(...". Thankful for any help!

[image: Tableau Screenshot]

Comment: I agree with Dharman.  This can be done easily in `tableau prep` first pivoting cols to rows, then removing nulls, then again pivoting rows to cols

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating data like that in Tableau is usually no-go. Nevertheless, you can try Tableau prep and you should be able to do what you need here. Or maybe a different tool (even excel).

With that said, even though you have the info in two rows, the default approach for Tableau is always to aggregate data, so even if you have many rows with similar cases, once you take it to a viz using City (for example) as a dimension, this issue shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Thank you! I will manipulate the data before uploading it in tableau then :)